# How to open a CHM help file from another CHM help file

Tags: windows, chm

I have a homepage application, it was used to launch individual applications, and the CHM of homepage has a brief description of individual applications and links to launch other CHM help file. How can I archive it? Is there any API in CHM what I can use? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install the second CHM file in the same directory as the first. Then, you can create a link with `href="name-of-other.chm"` (i.e. just put the name of the other file into the `href` attribute).

If they are not in the same directories, try absolute paths and pray that users always put the files in the same place.

Comment: Thanks for your information. It can work, but a download dialog will pop up if you click the link.

Comment: Try to put "its:" in front of the path.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the link Aaron mentioned, there is also something like master/slave chms, which is a deeper integration of CHMs:

- http://www.helpware.net/htmlhelp/how_to_merge_ctx2.htm
- http://www.helpware.net/htmlhelp/how_to_merge.htm